# Dynamic layout in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a layout in iOS that has to display the following horizontally:-

A static label, a map, a list of "dashboard" views.

The dashboard views is currently based on a collection view.

In an ideal world I'd put all the controls above in a scroll view, and enable horizontal scrolling, but this isn't working with the collection view because the collection view handles it's own scrolling.

[UPDATE]

I have disabled scrolling on the collection view, which I think should work, but the scroll view still doesn't scroll properly (I can now "bounce" horizontally and see the content off the screen, but if I take my finger off it just bounces back).

Comment: You can disable bouncing with this: `scrollView.bounces = NO`. If you can't see the content you probably didn't set the correct `contentSize`.

Comment: The 'contentSize' is probably the issue, but the content is databound, so I'd have to calculate the size at runtime - is it normal to have to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pageview controller and put all the views in it. 
[Vist this to learn about page view controller](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/)

Comment: Thanks, but I really want it all to be on the one page.